# GSL Uniform Random Number Generator

Tags: random

I want to use GSL's uniform random number generator. On their website, they include this sample code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>

 int
 main (void)
 {
   const gsl_rng_type * T;
   gsl_rng * r;

   int i, n = 10;

   gsl_rng_env_setup();

   T = gsl_rng_default;
   r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
     {
       double u = gsl_rng_uniform (r);
       printf ("%.5f\n", u);
     }

   gsl_rng_free (r);

   return 0;
 }
```

However, this does not rely on any seed and so, the same random numbers will be produced each time.

They also specify the following:

> The generator itself can be changed using the environment variable GSL_RNG_TYPE. Here is the output of the program using a seed value of 123 and the multiple-recursive generator mrg,
>
> ```
>  $ GSL_RNG_SEED=123 GSL_RNG_TYPE=mrg ./a.out
> ```

But I don't understand how to implement this. Any ideas as to what modifications I can make to the above code to incorporate the seed?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that a new seed is not being generated. If you just want a function that returns a darn random number, and care nothing about the sticky details of how it's generated, try this. Assumes that you have the GSL installed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

float keithRandom() {
    // Random number function based on the GNU Scientific Library
    // Returns a random float between 0 and 1, exclusive; e.g., (0,1)
    const gsl_rng_type * T;
    gsl_rng * r;
    gsl_rng_env_setup();
    struct timeval tv; // Seed generation based on time
    gettimeofday(&tv,0);
    unsigned long mySeed = tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec;
    T = gsl_rng_default; // Generator setup
    r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);
    gsl_rng_set(r, mySeed);
    double u = gsl_rng_uniform(r); // Generate it!
    gsl_rng_free (r);
    return (float)u;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Read [18.6 Random number environment variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-environment-variables.html) to see what that `gsl_rng_env_setup()` function is doing. It is getting a generator type and seed from environment variables.

Then see [18.3 Random number generator initialization](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-generator-initialization.html) - if you don't want to get the seed from an environment variable, you can use `gsl_rng_set()` to set the seed.

Comment: I don't know if someone has noticed it or not, but setting seed to 0 and 1 produce identical sets of random numbers although the documentation says otherwise. Other seeds, including 2, produce different sets. I would really like to know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

A complete answer to this question with a sample code can be seen in [in this link](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/gsl-discuss/2004-q1/msg00071.html).

Just for completeness I am putting a copy of the code for a function to create a seed here. It is written by Robert G. Brown: http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/ .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

unsigned long int random_seed()
{

 unsigned int seed;
 struct timeval tv;
 FILE *devrandom;

 if ((devrandom = fopen("/dev/random","r")) == NULL) {
   gettimeofday(&tv,0);
   seed = tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec;
 } else {
   fread(&seed,sizeof(seed),1,devrandom);
   fclose(devrandom);
 }

 return(seed);

}
```

But from my own experience with this function, I would say that the `dev/random` solution is very time consuming compared to the `gettimeofday()`, you can check it out. So, the `gettimeofday()` solution, might be better for you if its level of accuracy is enough:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

unsigned long int random_seed()
{
 struct timeval tv;
 gettimeofday(&tv,0);
 return (tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec);
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to answer Jamaia's question, which is how to incorporate a seed into the GSL random number generator, not how to come up with a number to use as a seed.

Comment: The way I read Jamaia's question, I feel it is asking how to generate a seed to give a different set of random numbers each time. I found this question (after 1.5 years of it being asked) because I had this exact problem (my interpretation of the question!). By now, Jamaia doesn't need an answer any more, but other readers having the same problem as me will be brought to this page and they want an answer.