# Setting GSL RNG seed correctly in Rcpp for model with repeat iterations

Tags: c++, r, performance, rcpp, gsl

I am writing a stochastic, process driven model of transmission of infection and diagnostic testing to detect infection. The model requires repeat random samples across multiple time steps and iterations. The faster my model can run, the better. For the random sampling in the model, parameters for the random samples can change at each time step in the model. I first wrote my model in R, and then in CPP (via the great Rcpp package). In Rcpp, using the R based random number generator, the model takes about 7% of the time to run as it took in R. I was advised that using GSL within CPP for random number generation is faster again. In the CPP model, with GSL based random sampling instead of R based random sampling, I get a marginal increase in speed. However, I am not sure that I am using the GSL based random sampler correctly.

My questions are:

1. Is it correct to only do the seed setting procedure once for the GSL RNG based on the time of day and use this same construct for all of my random draws (as I have done in code below)? I confess I do not fully understand the seed setting procedure within CPP for GSL as I am new to both. I have compared the distributions produced using both R-based and GSL-based RNG and they are very similar, so hopefully this bit is OK.

I obtained the code for setting the GSL seed according to the time of day from this Stack Overflow post:

[GSL Uniform Random Number Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768519/gsl-uniform-random-number-generator)

2. I was expecting a greater increase in speed using the GSL RNG. Is there anything I can do to maximize the speed of the GSL RNG?

I am using a Windows machine and the RStudio interface. I am sourcing the CPP functions from R using the Rcpp package. All of the packages and programmes were recently reinstalled. Here is the session info:
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

For context, I am a veterinary epidemiologist with R experience, but only two months into learning CPP. This is my first stack exchange query. Thanks in advance for your time!

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve written in CPP (using Rcpp in RStudio) and using the GSL based RNG. Please can somebody tell me if this is the correct way to set the GSL RNG seed? Is it OK to do the seed setting process just once at the top of the function?

```
// CPP code - function GSL RNG written using Rcpp on a CPP file in RStudio

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <RcppGSL.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]


Rcpp:: NumericMatrix check_cpp_gsl_rng(int n_iters,
                                 int min_unif,
                                 int max_unif,
                                 double exp_rate,
                                 double bernoulli_prob) 
{
  const gsl_rng_type * T;
  gsl_rng * r;
  gsl_rng_env_setup();
  struct timeval tv; // Seed generation based on time
  gettimeofday(&tv,0);
  unsigned long mySeed = tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec;
  T = gsl_rng_default; // Generator setup
  r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);
  gsl_rng_set(r, mySeed);

  // matrix to collect outputs
  
  Rcpp:: NumericMatrix Output_Mat(n_iters, 7); 
  
  for (int i = 0; i < n_iters; i++) // in real model, parameters may change for each iteration
    
  {
    // random exponential draws
    
    Output_Mat(i, 0) = gsl_ran_exponential(r , (1 / exp_rate)); // exp 1
    Output_Mat(i, 1) = gsl_ran_exponential(r , (1 / exp_rate)); // exp 2
    
    // random uniform draws
    
    Output_Mat(i, 2) = gsl_ran_flat(r, min_unif, max_unif); // unif 1
    Output_Mat(i, 3) = gsl_ran_flat(r, min_unif, max_unif); // unif 2
    
    // random Bernoulli draws

    Output_Mat(i, 4) = gsl_ran_bernoulli(r, bernoulli_prob); // Bernoulli 1
    Output_Mat(i, 5) = gsl_ran_bernoulli(r, bernoulli_prob); // Bernoulli 2
    
    
    Output_Mat(i, 6) = i; // record iteration number
  }
  
  return Output_Mat;
  
  gsl_rng_free(r);
  
  // end of function
  
}
```

The plot below shows a comparison of run speeds of the random sampling function implemented in R only, CPP using the R RNG and CPP using the GSL RNG (as in code above) based on 100 comparisons of 1000 iterations using the "microbenchmark" package.

[image: Comparison of run speeds of the random sampling function in R only, CPP using the R RNG and CPP using the GSL RNG based on 100 comparisons of 1000 iterations using the "microbenchmark" package.]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!   It is generall better to include auxiliary input directy instead of as links as links may rot whereas StackOverflow questions remain useful (and posted) for many years.  Please consider bringing the chart, and the tables or summaries into the question.  Also, it is a bit on the long end.  What is your actual question?  The RNG seeding for the GSL RNGs? Or the type of data drawn?  For that you could draw via R(cpp) and GSL and compare to the expected distribution.

Comment: This question is *really* long. I would trim it down and try to focus on something specific, otherwise the chances of this getting answered will be slim.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I have shortened the question and updated  it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A package you may find useful is my [RcppZiggurat](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=RcppZiggurat) ([github](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppziggurat)).  It revives the old but fast Ziggurat RNG for normal covariates and times it.  It use several other Ziggurat implementations as benchmarks -- including one from the GSL.

First, we can use its code and infrastructure to set up a simple structure (see below).  I first show that 'yes indeed' we can seed a GSL RNG:

```
> setseedGSL(42)
> rnormGSLZig(5)
[1] -0.811264  1.092556 -1.873074 -0.146400 -1.653703
> rnormGSLZig(5)    # different
[1] -1.281593  0.893496 -0.545510 -0.337940 -1.258800
> setseedGSL(42)
> rnormGSLZig(5)    # as before
[1] -0.811264  1.092556 -1.873074 -0.146400 -1.653703
>
```

Note that we need a global variable for an instance of a GSL RNG 'state'.

Second, we can show that Rcpp is actually faster that either the standard normal GSL generator or its Ziggurat implementation.  Using Rcpp vectorised is even faster:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> n <- 1e5
> res <- microbenchmark(rnormGSLZig(n), rnormGSLPlain(n), rcppLoop(n), rcppDirect(n))
> res
Unit: microseconds
             expr     min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
   rnormGSLZig(n) 996.580 1151.7065 1768.500 1355.053 1424.220 18597.82   100   b
 rnormGSLPlain(n) 996.316 1085.6820 1392.323 1358.696 1431.715  2929.05   100   b
      rcppLoop(n) 223.221  259.2395  641.715  518.706  573.899 13779.20   100  a 
    rcppDirect(n)  46.224   67.2075  384.004  293.499  320.919 14883.86   100  a 
>
```

The code is below; it is a pretty quick adaptation from my RcppZiggurat package.  You can `sourceCpp()` it (if you have RcppGSL installed which I used to 'easily' get the compile and link instructions to the GSL) and it will run the demo code shown above.

```
#include <Rcpp/Lighter>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]

class ZigguratGSL {
public:
    ZigguratGSL(uint32_t seed=12345678) {
        gsl_rng_env_setup() ;
        r = gsl_rng_alloc (gsl_rng_default);
        gsl_rng_set(r, seed);
    }
    ~ZigguratGSL() {
        gsl_rng_free(r);
    }
    double normZig() {
        const double sigma=1.0;
        return gsl_ran_gaussian_ziggurat(r, sigma);
    }
    double normPlain() {
        const double sigma=1.0;
        return gsl_ran_gaussian_ziggurat(r, sigma);
    }
    void setSeed(const uint32_t seed) {
        gsl_rng_set(r, seed);
    }
private:
    gsl_rng *r;
};

static ZigguratGSL gsl;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void setseedGSL(const uint32_t s) {
    gsl.setSeed(s);
    return;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector rnormGSLZig(int n) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector x(n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        x[i] = gsl.normZig();
    }
    return x;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector rnormGSLPlain(int n) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector x(n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        x[i] = gsl.normPlain();
    }
    return x;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector rcppLoop(int n) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector x(n);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        x[i] = R::rnorm(1.0,0.0);
    }
    return x;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector rcppDirect(int n) {
    return Rcpp::rnorm(n, 1.0, 0.0);
}


/*** R
setseedGSL(42)
rnormGSLZig(5)
rnormGSLZig(5)    # different
setseedGSL(42)
rnormGSLZig(5)    # as before


library(microbenchmark)
n <- 1e5
res <- microbenchmark(rnormGSLZig(n), rnormGSLPlain(n), rcppLoop(n), rcppDirect(n))
res
*/
```

PS  We write it as Rcpp.  Capital R, lowercase cpp.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful feedback and quick response.  Sorry yes that is the first thing I should have done re comparing the distributions of the random draws of each method. I have done this now and the distributions produced from the GSL RNG using the code above are very similar to those produced

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful feedback and quick response.  Re your  initial comment about comparing the distributions of the random draws of each method: Sorry, yes that is the first thing I should have done. I have done this now and the distributions produced from the GSL RNG using the code above are very similar to those produced using the R based RNG. This give me more confidence that the GSL RNG is doing what I think it should do. I will go back and edit the post with this and make it shorter. I tried to post images directly but apparently users need 10 credits to be able to do this..

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot about that constraint.  I will upvote your question as it is very solid (if too long <wink>).  But please update it or follow up otherwise: I hear quite often that the GSL is said to be faster, I generally have not found that to be true.  Of course, R has CRAN and there are other high-quality generators out there in other packages.  But my recommendation generally is to _trust R and its statistical computing experts_ before jumping (quickly) to alternatives.  It is easy to get small things wrong; R's code is widely used and tested.  We can trust it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying: "Note that we need a global variable for an instance of a GSL RNG 'state" and how the seed setting works. I was unsure about this before your answer. Re RcppZigurat: can it be used for non Normal distributions? I am working with exponential, uniform and Bernoulli distributions. Re: your worked example: does this suggest that  GSL RNG is slower than Rcpp RNG? Or can this only be said relating to the Normal distribution? My experiment above (with exponential, uniform and Bernoulli random samples) suggested the GSL RNG has a marginal advantage in speed.

Comment: Yes: AFAIK you need global state for the GSL RNG.  Random numbers are a 'hard' topic that a lot of work has gone into. R itself has different generators for uniform and normal covariates; I only timed normal.  Also AFAIK for other distributions one generally uses uniform draws (which I haven't timed) and used inversion so you would have to time this.  Lastly, Ziggurat is the fastest N(0,1) generator I know--but speed is not everything.  (There is an exponential generator in the original paper, I have not updated that.)   For good science, I would stick probably stick with R's RNG.

Comment: I have just seen your recent message - thanks - it sounds like the safety of sticking with the well known R RNG might outweigh any marginal speed advantage of introducing the GSL RNG which requires more programming knowhow.

Comment: That is what I would think.  Also note that there are different RNGs in R itself (see `?RNGkind`) so you may gain a little.  I found that while RNG speed differs the change is marginal relative to total compute time in many simulations.  "Correct first, then faster.".  Also: feel free to upvote (and thanks for accepting the answer).

Comment: OK thanks for your time- I will search for your publications about RcppZiggurat and see if I can use it in my model. I have tried to upvote the answer but Stack Exchange will not let me until I have 15 credits. I will upvote as soon as I can.

Comment: It's just a vignette in the package; I never got around to submitting it.  And sorry for my upvote nag then; I keep forgetting what is / isn't possible on 'day one' at StackOverflow.  Glad this helped you.